# how to count scope array length with specific value

Tags: angularjs

How to count the length of name attribute with value Jim which is 2 below.
     I want to write a condition in the controller based on  below.

```
   something like $scope.data.name.Jim.length==2
      // controller
      var app = angular.module('angularjs-starter', [])
      app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.data = [
        {
          "name": "Jim", "age" : 21
        }, {
          "name": "Jim", "age": 26
        }, {
          "name": "Alex",  "age" : 25
        }, {
          "name": "Max", "age": 22
        }
      ];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `filter` to get the element with name

**Controller**

```
var filteredData = $filter('filter')($scope.data, {"name": "Jim"})
if(filteredData.length > 2){
    //do conditional stuff here.
};
```

**HTML**

```
{{(data| filter: {"name": "Jim"}).length > 2}}
```

Comment: @user3853398 does it helped?